# How change React state if it is multidimensional array and contain objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, syncfusion

I have a state.

This state source in a file: dummy.js

This state contain complex data structure, this name **stackedCustomSeries**.

stackedCustomSeries is an array and contain two objects.

Each objects have several property: **dataSource**, xName, yName ...etc

The **dataSource** property contain **stackedChartData[0]**

The stackedChartData[0] is also an array.

The stackedChartData[0] contain two array.

These array's contain several objects.

Inside these objects have several x and y property.

I want to change this x and y properties value when I was clicked.

For example I click and pass data: 120

and in stackedChartData[0]   { x: 'Jan', **y: 111.1** }, would be >> { x: 'Jan', **y: 120** },

But How?

I import my datasource in a state in my App component

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  stackedCustomSeries, 
} from "../../data/dummy";

  const App = () => {
    const [customSeries, setCustomSeries] = useState(stackedCustomSeries);
  
    const handleClick = () => {
    //What write here ?
    };  
   
    return (          
        <div className="m-5">
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
            ChangeButton
          </button>         
        </div>
   
    );
  };
  
  export default App;
```

dummy.js

```
export const stackedChartData = [
  [
    { x: 'Jan', y: 111.1 },
    { x: 'Feb', y: 127.3 },
    { x: 'Mar', y: 143.4 },
    { x: 'Apr', y: 159.9 },
    { x: 'May', y: 159.9 },
    { x: 'Jun', y: 159.9 },
    { x: 'July', y: 159.9 },
  ],
  [
    { x: 'Jan', y: 111.1 },
    { x: 'Feb', y: 127.3 },
    { x: 'Mar', y: 143.4 },
    { x: 'Apr', y: 159.9 },
    { x: 'May', y: 159.9 },
    { x: 'Jun', y: 159.9 },
    { x: 'July', y: 159.9 },
  ],
];

export const stackedCustomSeries = [

  { dataSource: stackedChartData[0],
    xName: 'x',
    yName: 'y',
    name: 'Budget',
    type: 'StackingColumn',
    background: 'blue',

  },

  { dataSource: stackedChartData[1],
    xName: 'x',
    yName: 'y',
    name: 'Expense',
    type: 'StackingColumn',
    background: 'red',

  },

];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const handleClick = (value) => {
    const copiedCustomerSeries = [...customSeries];
    const updatedCustomerSeries = copiedCustomerSeries.map((cs, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        const updatedSingleCustomerSeries = {
          ...cs,
          dataSource: [...cs.dataSource].map((ds) =>
            ds.x === "Jan" ? { ...ds, y: value } : ds
          )
        };
        return updatedSingleCustomerSeries;
      } else return cs;
    });
    console.log(updatedCustomerSeries);
    setCustomSeries(updatedCustomerSeries)
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the chart series fill color and datasource using setState. Attached the tested sample and screenshot for your reference.

```
state = { background: 'transparent', data1:[
    { x: '2013', y: 962 },
    { x: '2014', y: 960 },
    //…
]} 
changeData = () => { 
   this.setState({ background: 'lightgreen', data1:[
    { x: '2013', y: 50 },
    { x: '2014', y: 60 },
    //…
   ]}) 
}

<ChartComponent id='charts'>
                    <SeriesCollectionDirective>
                    <SeriesDirective dataSource={this.state.data1} 
                    fill={this.state.fill}>
                        </SeriesDirective>
                    </SeriesCollectionDirective>
                </ChartComponent>
```

Sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t33w8h

Screenshots :

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: Thank you but I only use hooks